# Export multiple dataframes as power bi tables and vice versa

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, powerbi

I am trying to write a python script that will grab multiple different csv files from an input folder, then create a list of dataframes and display them as power bi tables in power bi. The below script is not loading any tables into power bi:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Data analysis case study'
csv_files = [os.path.join(path+"\\", file) for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.csv')]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(d) for d in csv_files]
```

Also, does someone know how to connect this python script to accept a folder path input from a power bi parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use Python for this.  PowerBI has a "Folder" data source that you can use to combine all the files in a folder into a single Power Query.

[image]

Comment: Browne i know. but this is as a test project to understand alternative ways to do the same import functionality. The idea is to use python to dynamically import different csv files as powerbi tables, from a folder asked as a user input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Import-multiple-dataframes-from-Python-script/m-p/2574694#M909504) answer, you won't be able to export multiple `dataframes` to power bi. However, you can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) all your `dataframes` into one `dataframe` and import it in power bi, like explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts). I didn't find anything special on exporting data from power bi to python, but you can always export it to a `.csv` file and import it with pandas.

Comment: all the csv files are different with different columns and data, so i dont think merging dataframes would help. Any other ideas? Sometimes only the last dataframe in the loop displays and not the 1st 2...

Comment: @sifar I don't think there is a way around merging your `dataframes`. It shouldn't be hard to [add all columns](https://www.statology.org/pandas-combine-two-columns/) or rows together. Maybe you can open multiple windows of power bi in an automated way and load one `dataframe` per window. Also, is there something wrong with my question edit or didn't you notice it? Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is not possible to give specific details.